# what is the difference between viewsate["x"] and __viewstate in view source?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net

i wanna to understand difference between  viewsate["x"] and __viewstate in view source

ie

in view source page there is view state in hidden control like:

```
<input type="hidden" name="__VIEWSTATE" id="__VIEWSTATE" value="dO3F9exemRdHoXxGHr"/>
```

but in c# i can create viewstate like:

```
viewstate["x"]="Hi";
```

so what is the difference???

and the string "Hi" where it be saved ? in this hidden or where?

Answer (score 2):

> When a page is rendered, it serializes its view state into a base-64
>   encoded string using the LosFormatter class and (by default) stores it
>   in a hidden form field. On postback, the hidden form field is
>   retrieved and deserialized back into the view state's object
>   representation, which is then used to restore the state of the
>   controls in the control hierarchy.

That means yes it saved in this `hidden field`, but it is `encoded`. Read [MSDN article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms972976.aspx) for more information. This quote is from **6.PARSING THE VIEW STATE**.

If you have any interest you can parse the ViewState and see his "real values". You can search for view state parser, after research I found this [Website](http://ignatu.co.uk/ViewStateDecoder.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

ViewState is a storage method on server side that is persisted on client side. What you're seeing is the two faces of the same coin

You use it on server side doing something like this

```
Viewstate["x"]="Hi";
```

And when the response is sent to the client, the ViewState storage is serialized and sent to the client in the form of an input field

```
<input type="hidden" name="__VIEWSTATE" id="__VIEWSTATE" value="dO3F9exemRdHoXxGHr"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

When you set view state using `ViewState["x"]`, it is stored in the hidden field `__VIEWSTATE`. It is first encoded, however, so you won't see "Hi" in that hidden field.